# How to calculate difference from one month to another in SQL? (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the difference of leads from one month to another many times.
Let´s say i had 1000 leads in july, 1200 leads in august and 1500 leads in september.

I know that I have to do final_var - initial_var / initial_var *100

How do i do it through SQL?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE leadsdata
(
    month integer,
    leads_count integer
)
```

Data as per you problem statement:

```
insert into leadsdata values
(7,1000),
(8,1200),
(9,1500)
```

The below is the SQL which you are trying to build:

```
select month, leads_count, 
lag(leads_count) over(order by month) ,
(( leads_count - lag(leads_count) over(order by month) ) / cast(lag(leads_count) over(order by month) as float) ) * 100
from LeadsData
```